# how can i use socket.io client for phoenix framework chat app

Tags: websocket, socket.io, phoenix-framework

I want to know is there are any way to use `socket.io` client for phoenix framework chat app .without using default `socket.js` client.i am change `nodejs` chat app to phoenix framework but i want to keep my old front-end client .that's why i want to figure out way to use `socket.io` client with phoenix framework.

```
let socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {user: user, status: status }})
socket.connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like its not possible:

> You cannot use another client like socket.io, because Phoenix channels and socketio use different messaging protocols. My recommendation is so use the phoenix.js client and continue to build great things with it :)

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phoenix-talk/aRnVOkc0sgs

Comment: Still not possible?